# Does react do a reverse pass over the tree when rendering?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

Ignoring the [reconciliation optimization heuristic](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html), can anyone definitively answer whether React does a reverse tree traversal, or only the primary Render traversal which starts at the root node and progressively renders the children?

This matters to me in a situation like this:

```
const Parent = (props) => {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <a />
      <B />
    </Parent>
  )
}

const B = (props) => {
  if (true) {
    return <p>I am the letter B</p>
  }
}
```

It appears to me that because the `Parent` always renders before the children, it cannot ask about their visibility and to make determinations like whether to add dividers, or how many sections loaded successfully, or anything else.

Is it true that the tree renders in the direction of `root -> leaves` and that is it?

> Context: I'm asking because in Angular there was a [bi-directional traversal](http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/#theoutput). It would go down, then climb back up, and if you understood this complexity, you could add the behaviors where you needed them based on the order of operations. Not saying it's better, or worse, but just as a frame of reference.

Comment: I believe react renders from children out, as in children lifecycle methods are called before parent lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

The React pattern is a one-directional flow of data from root downwards.

For the example you gave, child attributes would be stored in state (whether that be local component state, or application state) along with other properties that may be used in the logic that would *conditionally* render them.

The general pattern is state data flows downward, changes to state (events, etc.) flow upward.